# Find out how many arguments a block needs

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Let's say I have an array containing Blocks, and I need to assert that all of them expect a given number of arguments.

Is there a way to find this out programmatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is indeed possible, for any recent version of Clang.

The Apple ABI for Blocks is private but also [published](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Block-ABI-Apple.html). Since that document tells us the layout the compiler will use for a Block object, we can duplicate that information in a header file and use it to access the components of a Block.

Mike Ash's [MABlockForwarding project](https://github.com/mikeash/MABlockForwarding/blob/master/MABlockForwarding.m) does just that (see also the [article](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-10-28-generic-block-proxying.html)) -- much of the stuff at the top of this file is a copy-paste from the ABI doc. The thing that he created which we are interested in is the `BlockSig()` function:

```
static const char *BlockSig(id blockObj)
{
    struct Block *block = (__bridge void *)blockObj;
    struct BlockDescriptor *descriptor = block->descriptor;

    assert(block->flags & BLOCK_HAS_SIGNATURE);

    int index = 0;
    if(block->flags & BLOCK_HAS_COPY_DISPOSE)
        index += 2;

    return descriptor->rest[index];
}
```

which will return (for Blocks that have it (which they all do with recent Clang)), a [type encoding string](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html) describing the Block's return and argument types. From there, you can create an `NSMethodSignature` object, and ask it for its `numberOfArguments`:

```
 NSString * (^block)(int, NSArray *) = ^NSString * (int i, NSArray * a){
        return @"Oh, yeah!";
 };
 const char * types = BlockSig(block);
 NSMethodSignature * sig = [NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:types];
 [sig numberOfArguments];
```

The result there is 3, because it includes a hidden argument for the Block itself (and Blocks don't use the hidden `_cmd` argument or it would be 4).

Comment: Thanks Josh (and of course Mike Ash)! I integrated a few lines of Mike's code to extend my assertion tools and it worked! awesome

Answer (score 1):

The answer is you cannot. See the comment on Mike Ash's page regarding this:

[Search for Intropection](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/gcd-is-not-blocks-blocks-are-not-gcd.html) which [sends you here](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2009-September/006378.html)

So, what is your real problem? If you structure the arguments properly, you can insure that your system functions properly. For instance, you can do what C++ does with default values for arguments, and cast each block to a type that takes the max number of args, and always push that many items on the stack. Or you could always have the first argument be the number of arguments you are pushing on the stack. If you push objects and not numbers/pointers, then you r blocks can look at the class of each argument and dynamically adapt.